# What is the dimension of the space $W_2$ if $\text{dim}(W_1+W_2) = 2$, $\text{dim}(W_1 \cap W_2) = 1$ and $W_1 = \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is the dimension of the space $W_2$ if $\text{dim}(W_1+W_2) = 2$, $\text{dim}(W_1 \cap W_2) = 1$ and $W_1 = \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle$, where $a_1 = (1,0,0)$, $a_2=(2,0,0)$?

Okay so I know and understand that:

$$\text{dim}(W_1 \cap W_2) = \text{dim}W_1 + \text{dim}W_2 - \text{dim}(W_1 + W_2) $$

So my problem is with finding $\text{dim}W_1$ with the given information because the rest is just solving for $\text{dim}W_2$ as an unknown.

I have a definition of Dimension:

The dimension of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is denoted by $\text{dim}(V)$ and is defined to be the number of vectors in a basis for $V$. In addition, the zero vector space is defined to have zero dimension.

So how many vectors are in a basis for $W_1$. I thought you could just use the standard basis $(1,0,0)$ so $\text{dim}W_1=1$ but I'm not sure if that's correct? Surely both $a_1$ and $a_2$ can easily be written as a linear combination of this vector so there is $1$ vector in a basis for $W_1$. i.e. Let $S= \{ (1,0,0) \}$. This is linearly independent and it spans $W_1$ so it is a basis for $W_1$

$$1 = 1 + \text{dim}W_2 - 2$$

$$\text{dim}W_2 = 2$$

Comment: $$\text{dim}(W_1 + W_2) = \text{dim}W_1 + \text{dim}W_2 - \text{dim}(W_1 \cap W_2) $$

Comment: It's an identical statement

Comment: No, it is not. We subtract the intersection part.

Comment: Rearrange the equation. If you take the intersection part to the other side of the equation it is added. If you take the addition part to the other side as well then it is subtracted

Comment: oky. I understood. And you solved it right, $dim(W_1)=1$ because $a_2=2a_1$